# Get Type from string "IQueryable<SomeType>"

Tags: c#, generics, type-variables

I am trying to get Type variable from string

```
string queryableString = nameof(IQueryable) + "<" + entityType.FullName + " >";
Type type = Type.GetType(queryableString);
```

This works for any concrete class. But is returning null for IQueryable. 
Even the below returns null.

```
Type newType = typeof(SomeEntity).Assembly.GetType(nameof(IQueryable) + "<" + entityType.FullName + " >");
Type newType2 = Type.GetType(nameof(IQueryable) + "<" + entityType.FullName + " >" + "," + typeof(CaseHeader).Assembly.FullName);
Type newType3 = Type.GetType(nameof(IQueryable) + "<" + entityType.FullName + " >" + "," + typeof(IQueryable).Assembly.FullName);
```

Edit:
as per the answer from duplicate mark

```
string queryableString = typeof(IQueryable).FullName + "`1[" + entityType.FullName + " ]"; /*+ "," + typeof(CaseHeader).Assembly.FullName;*/
var queryReturnType = queryableString.GetTypeFromString();
```

The string generated from above is

```
System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Sfc.Wms.Foundation.Data.Entities.CaseHeader ]
```

This does not work either

This is not working either

```
System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Sfc.Wms.Foundation.Data.Entities.CaseHeader,Sfc.Wms.Foundation.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null ]]
```

Comment: Can you not just do `Type.GetType(queryableString).GetInterface(interfaceString)` ?

Comment: GetInterface accepts string as parameter

Comment: You need to use `[` rather than `<` as per the duplicate.

Comment: So pass in the string?